# Unable to print * (star) value with echo

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, centos

I have,

**my.sh**

```
while IFS= read -r line ; do
v1="$line";
t1=`echo $line | awk -F= '{print $2}'`
echo "$t1"
done < $1
```

**sample.txt**

```
say=hello
test=0 0/15 * * * ?
logs=valuelogs
```

**Output :**

```
[root@centos gen]# ./my.sh test.txt
hello
0 0/15 hello.txt 2.txt tmp.log my.sh sample.txt test.sh test.txt hello.txt 
2.txt tmp.log my.sh sample.txt test.sh test.txt hello.txt 2.txt tmp.log 
my.sh sample.txt test.sh test.txt ?
valuelogs
```

Here we get bad output due to executed command like `echo *` & its give list of file on current directory as output.

Is there any alternative solution for same ?

Comment: Related: [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `echo $line` inside the back quotes. Double quote the variable to prevent wildcard expansion:

```
t1=`echo "$line" | awk -F= '{print $2}'`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite your shell script as

```
awk -F= '{print $2}' "$1"
```

and avoid all the shell handling entirely (apart from the single quotes here and the `$1` parameter expansion which you want anyway); or even as an AWK script

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS="=" }

{ print $2 }
```